# Save GitHub repo reference with friendly comment?

Tags: git, github

How can I save references to 3rd party repositories with friendly comments in my account on github (all 3rd party repositories are github only, and i dont want to fork them)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could *star* them, but this doesn't allow to create a "friendly comment".

How about making a *gist* with links to your repositories?

Comment: Yes that's the issue, at time we feel to keep a list of repo with friendly comments and not to fork. Wish this feature could be added to github.

Answer (score 0):

There few possible solutions:

1. You can [**pin** your favorites repos to your github profile](https://github.com/blog/2191-pin-repositories-to-your-github-profile). But you can pin only your repos or repos you contribute to. You can pin only 6 repos. If you want to pin repos you haven't contributed to, can **fork** your favorite repos and the pin those forks to your profile.
2. If you wan't to share this repos among your friends or coworkers, you can click **Star** at repo's page. Your followers will see your stars in their timelines. This is the most usual way to share your favorite repos.
3. You can create a [**new gist**](https://gist.github.com/) and collect links to your favorite repos there. Also you can use Markdown to make it more readable and shiny decorated. Then people can **star**, **share** and **fork** your gist.
4. You can make a new repo (called *links* or *favorites*, for example) and collect all your links there (in `README.md` file). Then you can **pin** this repo to your profile page.